# *ngFor with two let

Tags: angular, ngfor

How to generate options of a selection with nested `*ngFor`?

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label></mat-label>
  <select[(ngModel)]="data">
    <option *ngFor="let payload1 of payload;let payload2 of payload1" [value]="payload2.id">
      {{ payload2.name}}
    </option>
    </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let payload1 of payload;>
  <option *ngFor="let payload2 of payload1" [value]="payload2.id">
</ng-container>
```

Edit:

```
<select[(ngModel)]="data">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let payload1 of payload;>
     <option *ngFor="let payload2 of payload1" [value]="payload2.id">
   </ng-container>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you,
But is it possible to make it work with a select?

Comment: You want two selects? Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ng-container`, which does not create a DOM object but allows to manipulate variables & template code. So that would give you:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let payload1 of payload">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let payload2 of payload1">
    <option [value]="payload2.id">{{ payload2.name }}</option>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

You can also put the second `ngFor` inside the `option` tag if you prefer.

Comment: thank you,
But is it possible to make it work with a select?

Comment: Sure, just wrap this code with your `select` object. This code just replaces your `<option...` line, remaining stays the same.

Comment: Great, please accept an answer & upvote answers your like to close your question :)